# Rails Forms Two Selects One Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, parameters

Im trying to make a form where the user get to pick a codename with is made up of two parts. It can successfully create and save the form but it only saves the animal part of the codename.

```
<h2>Join Game</h2>
<%= form_for([@game, @game.players.build]) do |f| %>
<p>

<% adjArray = ["Alert","Ancient","Brave","Charming","Cheerful","Courageous","Deafening","Determined","Eager","Enchanting","Enthusiastic","Fancy","Friendly","Hissing","Loud","Mad","Old","Proud","Quick","Screeching","Silent","Silly","Slippery","Sour","Sparkling","Squeaky","Strong","Thundering","Victorious","Wild","Witty","Wonderful"]%>
<%= select(:player, :codename, adjArray) %>
<% animalArray = ["Ant","Bird","Cat","Chickken","Cow","Dog","Elephant","Fish","Fox","Horse","Humming Bird","Kangaroo","Lion","Monkey","Penguin","Pig","Rabbit","Sheep","Tiger","Whale","Wolf"] %>
<%= select(:player, :codename, animalArray) %>


<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

The controller code

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
        @player = @game.players.create(player_params)
        redirect_to game_path(@game)
    end

    private
    def player_params
        params.require(:player).permit(:codename, :alive, :target)
    end
end
```

Ps. This is in Rails, the players belongs to games and a Games has many players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use virtual attributes to hold the values for the two parts of the codename. I'd also move the arrays into your Player model and add validations for the virtual attributes.

Player model (add arrays, virtual attributes and validations):

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_codename_parts
  after_validation :save_codename

  attr_accessor :codename_adj, :codename_animal

  ADJ_ARRAY = ["Alert","Ancient","Brave","Charming","Cheerful","Courageous","Deafening","Determined","Eager","Enchanting","Enthusiastic","Fancy","Friendly","Hissing","Loud","Mad","Old","Proud","Quick","Screeching","Silent","Silly","Slippery","Sour","Sparkling","Squeaky","Strong","Thundering","Victorious","Wild","Witty","Wonderful"]

  ANIMAL_ARRAY = ["Ant","Bird","Cat","Chickken","Cow","Dog","Elephant","Fish","Fox","Horse","Humming Bird","Kangaroo","Lion","Monkey","Penguin","Pig","Rabbit","Sheep","Tiger","Whale","Wolf"]

  validates :codename_adj, inclusion: { in: ADJ_ARRAY }
  validates :codename_animal, inclusion: { in: ANIMAL_ARRAY }

  # your existing Player model code...

  private

    def set_codename_parts
      return if codename.blank?
      @codename_adj ||= codename.split(' ')[0]
      @codename_animal ||= codename.split(' ')[1]
    end

    def save_codename
      self.codename = [codename_adj, codename_animal].join(' ')
    end
end
```

Player controller (change your player_params method):

```
def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:codename_adj, :codename_animal, :target, :alive)
end
```

Form (remove your current array declarations and select(...)):

```
<%= select :player, :codename_adj, Player::ADJ_ARRAY %>
<%= select :player, :codename_animal, Player::ANIMAL_ARRAY %>
```